# How do we validate the equality of function while reducing the indeterminate form to simpler function?

Tags: limits

To evaluate the limit of an indeterminate form, we need to reduce the function to its simplest form in order to get a meaningful answer.

For example: $f(x_1)$=${x^3-1\over x-1}$, evaluate $lim_{x->1} {x^3-1\over x-1}$; putting  $x=1$ in the equation we get $\frac 00$.

We reduce the equation to the simpler form,

$f(x_1)$=${x^3-1\over x-1}$ = ${(x-1)(x^2+x+1)\over (x-1)}$= $(x^2+x+1)$$=$$f(x_2)$

Therefore,

$lim_{x->1} (x^2+x+1)$;  putting $x=1$  we get,   $lim_{x->1} f(x_2)$$=3$

It suggests from the above that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=3$
; the functions are equal.

But, the condition of equality of function:

For $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$,

$dom f(x_1)=dom f(x_2)$ and $range f(x_1)=range f(x_2)$

We see, the domain of $f(x_1) = {R}-(1)$ and domain of $f(x_2)=R$

It implies, that $dom f(x_1)dom≠f(x_2)$ contradiction! The functions seem unequal.

How does the validity of equality of function holds, not only here for general case as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that:
$$
{x^3-1\over x-1} \neq x^2+x+1
$$
since the domains of these two functions are not equal. However, these two functions are equal everywhere else other than at $x = 1$. Hence, since evaluating the **limit** of a function $f$ as $x \to a$ does not depend on the actual value of $f(a)$, we are allowed to use the equality:
$$
\lim_{x\to1}{x^3-1\over x-1} = \lim_{x\to1}(x^2+x+1)
$$